# glm precision qualifier

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

What actually "precision qualifier" do, in the [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net) library?

P.S. At first I thought that it switch between float/double/long double...
But than I found d -version of mat4 `dmat4` (with double type).

P.P.S. I use it in C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From:** *http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.1/api/a00229.html*

> The GLSL language allows the user to define the precision of a
>   particular variable. In OpenGL's GLSL, these precision qualifiers have
>   no effect; they are there for compatibility with OpenGL ES's precision
>   qualifiers, where they do have an effect.
>
> C++ has no language equivalent to precision qualifiers. So GLM
>   provides the next-best thing: a number of typedefs of the Template
>   types that use a particular precision.
>
> None of these types make any guarantees about the actual precision
>   used.